# Maven cannot find local artifact

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a installed a local artifact that is not available via maven central:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/app/x/ema.jar -DgroupId=org.x -DartifactId=elektron -Dversion=3.0.4 -Dpackaging=jar
```

The local repository now has the structure:

```
user@server:~/.m2/repository/org/x/elektron/3.0.4# ll
total 592
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Mar 28 11:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Mar 28 11:43 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 588185 Dec  9 20:12 elektron-3.0.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    463 Mar 28 11:43 elektron-3.0.4.pom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    175 Mar 28 11:43 _remote.repositories
```

The contents of elektron-3.0.4.pom are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.x</groupId>
  <artifactId>elektron</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.4</version>
  <description>POM was created from install:install-file</description>
</project>
```

My pom has the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.x</groupId>
    <artifactId>elektron</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

When I build via Jenkins, I get the following error:

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.x:elektron:jar:3.0.4 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.253 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-28T11:35:27-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ampere: Could not resolve dependencies for project y:ampere:jar:0.1.8-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.x:elektron:jar:3.0.4 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I've tried recommended solutions (deleting/reinstalling, removing *.repositories files), but none seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try with mvn clean install? also your jar file have the user root, all yours others jars have same user? maybe its a user roles access problem

Comment: Hmm.. mvn clean install works from the command line. Looks like this is a jenkins problem?

Comment: You installed it as "user" and not as "jenkins", so Jenkins is unable to find it.

Answer (score 0):

When viewing my Jenkins .m2 repo, it contained the following:

```
user@server:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/x/elektron/3.0.4# ll
total 596
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins   4096 Mar 28 12:03 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins   4096 Mar 24 15:23 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins    244 Mar 28 11:23 elektron-3.0.4.jar.lastUpdated
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins    244 Mar 28 11:23 elektron-3.0.4.pom.lastUpdated
```

I manually added the following two files, and it worked:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    588185 Mar 28 12:03 elektron-3.0.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root       463 Mar 28 12:03 elektron-3.0.4.pom
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the command `mvn clean install -U`  , this will allow you to download or force updates on your local repository, which will download from the remote repo and copy to your local repo.

Comment: -U does not help for this particular dependency, as it is not available from a remote repo.